# Laravel Schema Builder | Unique, Case Sensitive Column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel's schema builder with mysql to make a unique column. But when I use the unique method it is case **insensitive**. I need it to be case **sensitive**. How can I do that?

Schema:

```
Schema::create('item', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('key')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

First entry into database:

```
$i = new Item;
$i->key = "Random_Key";
$i->save();
```

Second entry into database (returns duplicate entry error):

```
$i = new Item;
$i->key = "random_key";
$i->save();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use [character sets and collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html) for specifying [case sensitive columns in mySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Laravel has the [collate and charset column modifiers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php#L16) in mySQL for this purpose

So, you may use something like:  `$table->string('key')->charset('utf8')->collate('utf8_cs')->unique()`

As the OP stated, here's what worked for him:

`$cs = $table->string('key')->unique();`

```
$cs->collation = 'utf8_bin';
```

Comment: I tried `utf8_bin` as the collatation, but when I migrated the tables it won't change the collation. I have to go in to the database and manually change the collation.

I found a solution to this though. All you have to do is something like this... `$cs = $table->string('key')->unique();` then you need to do the following... `$cs->collation = 'utf8_bin';`

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I'll edit my answer to include what worked for you

Comment: This helped me, expecially the ->collation('utf8_bin') at the end (without it it does not work)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the type of the column VARBINARY?

`DB::statement('ALTER TABLE item MODIFY id VARBINARY(64);');`

Comment: If you have a question please create new one. This section is only to provide answers