# Create unique case insensitive column for MySQL and SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sqlite

I am using Laravel 8 and I have this table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('username')->nullable()->unique();
});
```

In MySQL the username is caseinsensitive unique. This means I cannot have two rows like this:

```
id | username
1  | MAX
2  | max
```

However, in SQLite, it its casesensitive unique, meaning the above example would be possible.

I found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20914992 how the raw SQLITE command is for this. However, I don't want to use a raw SQL command, because I would like that my migrations work for both, SQLite and MySQL.

I found a similar question at [Laravel Schema Builder | Unique, Case Sensitive Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044356/laravel-schema-builder-unique-case-sensitive-column) which asks for the opposite and suggests to use the `collation` [migration-modifier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers) to set to an case-sensitive collocation. Unfortunately, the collation does not seem to work for SQLite on Laravel but only for (MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQL Server).

How can I adjust the migration, so that the column is unqiue case insensitive for MySQL and SQLite?

Comment: For Mysql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463764/are-unique-indices-case-sensitive-in-mysql

Comment: you tried binary? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html